# How can I check my permissions in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp

I have my virtual machine (Windows XP) and some user account assigned to me. I also belong to several groups. What I actually know is my user name, password and a couple of other things that I have remembered or wrote down.

The question is: Where can I find a place on my virtual machine or maybe on a web page, where I can check the groups I belong to and my permissions and other properties of my AD account?

Comment: Ok, so my question is off-topic. Sorry for that. I could migrate it to other site, but don't see the option. I don't want to delete it, since Mathias R. Jessen gave me a very helpful answer and got deserved points. What shall I do?

Comment: Leave it here, It is a great question and has helped me too, thanks for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't give out too many useful information about what Operating System you are using, but these procedures will be similar for Vista/7/8/8.1:

To find out what groups you are a member of:

1. Log on to your virtual machine (assuming it is joined to the domain) with your AD user account
2. Open up a Command Prompt
3. Type in `whoami /groups` and hit enter

The `whoami` command will now list all the groups that you are a member of

---

To get a more detailed view of your user accounts properties in Active Directory:
*Assuming you're running Windows 8(.1) Enterprise, see below for Windows XP*

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features
2. Select "Turn Windows Features on or off"
3. Goto to Remote Server Administration Tools -> Role Administration Tools
4. Check the "AD DS and AD LDS Tools" option and install:
   [image: RSAT Tools for AD]

Now you can launch the Active Directory Users and Computers MMC (`dsa.msc`), find your account and explore the object properties.

Alternatively, you can use the Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell to retrieve the account object and see what Properties emerge:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser "Ryszard Dzegan" -Properties *|fl
```

---

For AD Administration/Access from Windows XP:

1. Download the [`Windows Server 2003 Administration Pack`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16770) and install it
2. Active Directory Users and Computers should now be available from Control Panel -> Administrative Tools